# Peer to Peer data transfer using WebRTC in ios.

Tags: ios, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

How to transfer peer to peer data using WebRTC in iOS (swift or objective c). It is related to RTCDataChannel class but there is no documentation or sample to transfer data from one peer to another in iOS. 
It will help me to achieve!

1) Peer to Peer file transfer
2) Peer to Peer realtime raw data transfer.

Comment: Check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850376/impelementation-of-rtcdatachannel-of-webrtc-in-ios